# ZOTAC IONITX-F-E drivers for windows 7 (32 / 64)

Tags: windows-7, drivers, 64-bit, 32-bit

I bought this [Zotac Motherboard](http://zotacusa.com/specsheet/IONITX-F-E.pdf) like 4 years ago, and can't find the drivers for it.

i've looked high and low and found nothing so far.

Can anyone give me a hand, or point in me in the right direction.

I've tried windows automatic update, and it installed funky video drivers that really don't work well with the motherboard.

Note: I obviously don't have the box/disc anymore.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried contacting zotac support? http://www.zotac.com/support/contact-support.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Zotac ION ITX-F-E Nvidia Chipset Driver for Vista/Win7](http://drivers.softpedia.com/get/MOTHERBOARD/Nvidia/Zotac-ION-ITX-F-E-Nvidia-Chipset-Driver-for-Vista-Win7.shtml):

Driver download link http://drivers.softpedia.com/progDownload/Zotac-ION-ITX-F-E-Nvidia-Chipset-Driver-for-Vista-Win7-Download-103390.html

**Zotac ION ITX-F-E Nvidia Chipset Driver for Vista/Win7 description**

```
Chipset: MCP7A-ION
CPU Socket: BGA 437
Dimensions: 6.7in x 6.7in - 170mm x 170mm
Form Factor: Mini ITX
FSB: 533 MHz
Memory Size: Up to 4GB RAM
Memory Slots: 2x 240 pin DDR2 DIMM
Memory Type: DDR2 667/800
Onboard Audio: 5.1
Onboard LAN: 10/100/1000Mbps
Onboard Video: GeForce 9400M
Package Contents: 3 SATA cable
1 SATA power cable
1 WiFi antenna
1 WiFi bracket
PCI Express x16: 1
Power Connector: 20 Pin
RAID: 0/1/0+1
SATA: 3 + 1 eSATA
USB: 10 (6 on back panel, 4 via pin header)
Video Ports: D-Sub + DVI-D + HDMI
```

Other drivers at [Zotac ION ITX-F-E Drivers](http://drivers.softpedia.com/downloadTag/Zotac+ION+ITX-F-E+Drivers) and [Zotac ION ITX-F-E Nvidia Chipset Driver For Windows Vista,Windows 7 x64](http://drivers.downloadatoz.com/vendor_zotac/zotac-ion-itx-f-e-nvidia-chipset/)